# Problems accessing a Cisco Router from Ubuntu 18.04 via SSH

Tags: 18.04, openssh, cisco

I have an Ubuntu virtual machine (server) connected to a Cisco router where I'm trying to establish a SSH session to this device. They are connected back-to-back so there are no additional network elements in between them. I can establish SSH sessions from this Ubuntu VM with other VMs as OpenSSH is enabled in the Ubuntu VM.

On the router side, a crypto key of 2048 (RSA) was generated

The status is as follows:

```
*R1#sh ip ssh

SSH Enabled - version 2.0
Authentication timeout: 120 secs; Authentication retries: 3
Minimum expected Diffie Hellman key size : 1024 bits
IOS Keys in SECSH format(ssh-rsa, base64 encoded):
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC8PJx8zmO411wIoin0nieU1cAviDhjImhObA3WaOVp
jh/O6UKiICMNWwmCgAxdZXa70deVOd9UKaR4HVxoUauMBFUFUv+IQvkBoc3VKcN3g47+Ac9U/ytd8zUI
EL4wGTHfQoPZBvF5A3iwnIHM2TFJVZt9eRLEthST/sTB+E9j2n1PT0C0js0gRNVw79ZyUA8aR2CZI5I+
sGd7mqBYdgqePL5H/tUeVTg/I2gXJ6xv7yrN904utRyAT+IieQIh6pWALIRmEl7NVyn/E6OvdUaeRfqM
TsD956uJkA2MTLrQ+VJBVoCNOHk/PujzqCYg+sod1QgSZZQW7bhpLkP7bUSt*
```

When I try to access the router from the VM with the following command:

```
root@Ubuntu-VM:~/.ssh# ssh user@10.1.1.1
```

I get the following message:

```
Unable to negotiate with 10.1.1.1 port 22: no matching cipher found.  Their offer: aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

On the router console, I get the following output:

```
%SSH-3-NO_MATCH: No matching cipher found: client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com server aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
```

In both cases, the `No matching cipher found` message is displayed; but, I don't know on which side is the problem.

Any advise would be appreciated.

Comment: It means that the cryptographic algorithm choices offered by the client didn't match ANY of the cryptographic algorithm choices offered by the server (`aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc`). Read `man ssh`, use the `-v` option, maybe try the `-1` and `-2` options.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was in the `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file as ciphers are disabled by default on Ubuntu 18.04.
Once I removed the comment sign (`#`), I could log in to the router with no problem.

Answer (score 1):

Just add `-c` param with one of the supported ciphers (aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc):

```
ssh -c aes256-cbc user@10.1.1.1
```